# Mysql ABS(AVG(field_name)) as total returns float number

Tags: mysql, math, floating-point, average

I'm trying to get integer value with ABS and AVG functions in MySQL but it's still giving me float value.

```
select ABS(AVG(quantity)) as average from stocks
```

This query should return absolute integer value but it's return float value like `125.889`. What's the matter ?

Answer (score 4):

`ABS()` stands for absolute, it doesn't return integer necessarily.

You'll have to use one of the **[mathematical functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html)** like `FLOOR()`, `CEILING()`, `ROUND()`, `TRUNCATE( ,0)` or cast the result to `INTEGER`.

Comment: Thanks, `ROUND()` function solved my problem. I missed it, sorry.

Comment: You can't use `floor` nor `ceiling` because "For exact-value numeric arguments, the return value has an exact-value numeric type. For string or floating-point arguments, the return value has a floating-point type."